# NLP - Open Vocabulary Word Embedding

Tags: python, nlp, neural-network, word2vec

How can I convert words to vectors (Word embedding) if I don't have a predefined dictionary of words? Most word embedding implementations like [Word2vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/) and [GloVe](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) have a fixed dictionary of words. The input to the neural networks are one-hot encoded and the hidden layer sizes also depend on the vocab size, which makes adding a new word later on without re-training all the vectors again impossible. I need a network that outputs a fixed dimensional vector for any arbitrary word input. But how to input the 'word' into the network? one hot encoding is not possible, as i don't have a fixed dictionary of words.

Will converting the word to a trigram vector or a bigram vector work? Trigram vectors have been used for Sentence embedding ([Deep Sentence Embedding Using Long Short-Term Memory Networks](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.06922.pdf)), but I doubt if it will work equally as well for word embedding, as there are changes in both the network architecture (Word embedding uses shallow network whereas sentence embedding uses RNNs) and the auxiliary task. Please help.

Note:

By "converting to trigram vector" I mean the following :

- Let the input word be "CAT" Add #s at the beginning and at the end :
  "#CAT#"
- List all the possible tri-grams:  #CA, CAT, AT#
- Each trigram is converted to a one hot encoded vector of dimension NxNxN 
  where N is my character set size. eg., E("#CA") = {0,0,0,0,0,...,0,**1**,0,0,0}
- The one hot encoded vector of every trigram of the word is added to
  get the "tri-gram vector" of the word.
  e.g., trigram_vec("CAT") = {0,0,0,0,...0,**1**,0,0,...0,0,**1**,0,...0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0}

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Is it important for the word's trigram vector to uniquely identify it?  If so, then this one-hot encoding doesn't necessarily work.  For instance, you cannot differentiate "Mississippi" from Mississississippi".  In general, a 3-letter sequence repeated once is indistinguishable from one repeated several times.  There are also letter sequences in which you could swap pairs of 1 or 2 letters within the word and get the same trigram vector.

Comment: How can you output a reasonable vector for a previously unseen word?

Comment: @Prune  Repetition of trigrams wont be a problem.If a trigram is repeted twice, the one hot encoded vector of that trigram will be added up twice into the trigram vector of the word and would look like   {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0}. (2 for the trigram which repeated twice). Because information regarding the order in which the trigrams occur in the word is lost, this is certainly not a one on one function and can not be decoded directly. But conflicts will be very less, and an RNN could be easily trained to predict the word given a trigram vector and some context.

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin "You shall know a word by the company it keeps"- John Rupert Firth.

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin Suppose that the model is used for web search. Often new words and hash tags pop up, related to some particular event, especially in the news. For e.g., "september 11" has special significance and can not be considered as an arbitrary date and fed into the network as "september <digit><digit>". Therefore it would be useful to have a model with no fixed vocab,  and not requiring to re train the model for adding a single word to the dictionary.

Comment: @farizrahman4u if you're interested in compound terms, I think you just need to add a composition "level" to your network. (I can elaborate on that, but you can probably find the relevant resources on your own.) However, if you are interested in the network to be able to represent arbitrary unseen words, I don't think it's a solvable problem with any technology because word sense in English, in general, is not defined  by the characters or syllables comprising it.

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin Just like a one hot encoded vector, which doesnt represent any word sense, i just need some kind of encoding to input the word into the network. The encoding is not supposed to encode the meaning of the word, just a convinient fixed length vector. This can not be one hot encoding, because i dont have a fixed vocab. What i am asking for is an alternative to one hot encoding, which do not require a fixed vocab.Thanks for your involvment in this question.

Comment: @farizrahman4u what do you think of using n-hot encoding (i.e. put 1s for all the words present in your input)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90002/discussion-between-farizrahman4u-and-vsevolod-dyomkin).

Comment: Some articles that might help: _"Better Word Representations with Recursive Neural Networks for Morphology"_ - using morphemes to learn word representations, _"Curriculum learning"_ (Bengio et al) - incidentally deals with increasing the size of the vocabulary over time.